# Name of proton directly bonded to a functional group e.g. carbonyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, terminology

For example, a carbon bonded to a carbonyl group is the alpha carbon, and has alpha protons. Following that there are beta and gamma carbons and protons.
Is there a specific name for the proton in an aldehyde that is bonded to the carbonyl, outside of "aldehyde proton" etc?

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. You may use "aldehyde hydrogen", also. The problem is that it is not a proton (H+) although the usage is common.

Comment: @user55119 thanks. Do you know what the distinction between calling an H bonded to a carbon a hydrogen or a proton is? In all my lectures we have always said "proton"

Comment: As I said, the term "proton" is often used loosely.

Comment: it is a hydrogen atom, a proton  + electron, that bonds to a carbon, atom, not just  proton.

Comment: One can see it as a proton bound due to electrons.... Still I've upvoted Poutnik comment. Origin of the loose use of the term proton might be in HNMR. But in the latter case the term has a physical ground.